# Swift WebView WebRTC Cannot Show Two Peers At Same Time

Tags: ios, swift, webview, webrtc

I want to use WebRTC through WebView.
I use a phone with iOS system version: 14.4,
And my mac's Xcode version: 12.4
When open the page to use WebRTC,
first, it will show a alert message for camera and microphone privacy.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/027m2.png)

When I click the "Allow" button,
then will show a live broadcast view with the image on my side.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGJW1.jpg)

After I click the "X" button in the view's upper left,
Another live broadcast view show up, with the image on my partner's side.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq0Mb.jpg)

Then I click the "X" button in the view's upper left again.
It finally show the origin view of the web page.
But the image all frozen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX0dI.jpg)

Actually, I only add privacy about microphone and camera in info.plist of this project.

So, my question is how to remove the live broadcast view, and connect two peers in the origin page without frozen status.